# Adding new root in the treelist during runing

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hii

I am using xtratreelist.In this i have created an unbound treelist.

I added a button in the form.Now i need the button to function such that when i click on the button it should add a new root in the treelist.how it can be done..please help me from the basic please...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from [How to: Create Nodes in Unbound Mode in Code](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5559) showing how to create a root node:

```
TreeListNode parentForRootNodes = null;
    TreeListNode rootNode = tl.AppendNode(
        new object[] { "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Germany, Obere Str. 57", "030-0074321" }, 
        parentForRootNodes);
```

Comment: But can u give the code for creating child nodes from the child node..t